# Is there any difference between splitting application in app.yaml or webapp2 URI router

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Consider the two following scenarios:

There are two url handlers in app.yaml

```
handlers:
- url: /main
  script: main.app1
- url: /secondary
  script: secondary.app2
```

and URI router in main.py

```
app1 = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/main', MainHandler)])
```

and another in secondary.py

```
app2 = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/secondary', SecondaryHandler)])
```

**vs**

There is one url handler in app.yaml

```
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.app
```

and the URI router decides the handler

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
        ('/main', MainHandler),
        ('/secondary', SecondaryHandler)
      ])
```

Is there any difference in how the App Engine imports the two scenarios? If all requests are for MainHandler, does the App Engine import the files associated with SecondaryHandler at all in the first scenario or does an instance always import each handler when it is first initialized?

Obviously these are different ways to partition the application logically, but I'm asking if there are any associated performance considerations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a lazy handler in webapp2 to optimize loading and use a single app.
See this link : https://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/routing.html#lazy-handlers

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was after. Do you know if splitting the application in app.yamp has the same effect for importing as the lazy handlers do?

Comment: If you use multiple apps and an app is not used, it is also not loaded. But if you do not use lazy handlers, and an app is used, all handlers and dependencies (imports) will be loaded.

Comment: Does this apply to the very first time the app has to be loaded (like after deploying, or for each new instance)? Or is it for every request? Does that mean that the choices are: pay the loading cost once per instance vs. pay the loading cost for every (first) new request that matches each lazy handler?

Comment: Once per instance and if the app is used by a request. You can use a warmup: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Warmup_requests

Comment: @Romz dude it applies after instance spins up. So your app is running on an instance with zero handlers loaded. It receives a request for '/make/awesome' and loads the handler 'make.awesome' -- now for the life of that instance, it will never again have to load 'make.awesome' and it will not, as of that first request, have loaded any of the other handlers you have put in lazy loading, like say, 'make.delicious', 'make.wealth' etc :)

Comment: The link above is dead and appears to have moved to http://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/routing.html#lazy-handlers.